# MVC builds html page but does not show it

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem concerning Asp.net MVC.

I have an Index.cshtml page with the following javascript

```
      $('#employeeTable tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {
            var mitarbeiterId = table.row(this).data().Id;                
            $.post('@Url.Action("IndexCompletion")', { id: mitarbeiterId });
        });
```

This basically just gets me the id of an employee and calls this ActionResult in my Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexCompletion(int id)
    {
        Mitarbeiter ma = new LeistungserfassungService.LeistungserfassungService().GetMitarbeiterById(id);
        return View("IndexCompletion", new IndexCompletionViewModel{Mitarbeiter = ma});
    }
```

Now i hoped that this will show me the following page:

```
    @model Leistungserfassung.Models.IndexCompletionViewModel

    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Completion";
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }

   <div class="content">
       <h2>Completion</h2>
       @Model.Mitarbeiter.Nachname
   </div>
```

But what happens now is, it builds the page successfully, as i can see on the networking tab in Google Chromes dev tools, but does not redirect to it. 
Also when i directly try to navigate to this .cshtml file, the browser tells me it can not be found.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem on this? 
I am very new to javascript so i am grateful for any advice!

Thanks in advance and sorry for the german parts in my code.

Comment: The whole point of making an ajax call is to stay on the same page. If you want to go to a new page, do **not** use ajax.

Comment: What would be the correct way to get a Post call like this done without using AJAX ? I was not aware that $.Post is shorthand for an ajax call.

Comment: Just have a form with a submit button (or multiple forms in your case)

Comment: I am trying to use the doubleclick event of datatables, what would that look like if i try to submit the form?

Comment: You can always call the `.submit()` event in your `doubleclick()` handler (but its an awful UI so recommend you do not do it)

Comment: Oh well thank you good Sir

Comment: Its pointless to make an ajax call, then send data back to the client so it can redirect instead of just making the redirect in the POST method

Comment: Yes i see. Again i did not know that .Post is the shorthand version for an ajax call. Since i am very new to jquery, i thought it works like "Window.url.href" just as a POST method. I would appreciate any recommendation on how this would be a nice and clean POST to my Controller to call my View

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys.
Now that i understand that $.post creates an AJAX call, I changed my code to create a form on Doubleclick and submit it with my Id. 
(Which is the far better way to solve this problem)

```
        $('#employeeTable tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function () {
            var mitarbeiterId = table.row(this).data().Id;

            $('<form action=@Url.Action("IndexCompletion") method="POST">' +
                  '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + mitarbeiterId + '">' +
                  '</form>').submit();
        });
```

This works great. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're making an async ajax call to the server using JavaScript this means JavaScript needs to redirect the user to another page.  So, in order for this to happen your controller post method should return a response to JavaScript (most likely JSON) which will have a redirect link (key, value) item to then redirect.

Comment: I did not even know that $.post() creates an async ajax call. I really hoped i could just pass the object directly. I will try your solution and post it if i get it to run! Thanks

Comment: Yes it's the short hand version in jQuery. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/  the server needs to send back a success message that your ajax call should use as a postback.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

```
var jsonObj = JSON.stringify({
                'id': mitarbeiterId
            });

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("IndexCompletion")',
            type: "Post",
            data: jsonObj,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
               $("#divForReturnedViewFromController").html(msg);
            },
        });
```